# Echo saved date in mysql in diffrent HTML divs?

Tags: php, html, mysql, date

i am using jquery date picker for date selection and saved that date in the mysql table column.
the date saved in this format `Tuesday, 8 April, 2014` .
Now i am wanted to show each word of the date in different div's for different formatting  of each word.

like `<div>Tuesday</div>` `<h1>8</h1>` `<h2>April</h2>` `<p>2014</p>`.

How it is possible in PHP.

Comment: you need to save date in different columns

Comment: It would be way easier to store the above format in the database using the comfort DATE format provided by your database. Therefore, storing the date as DATE format (YYYY-MM-DD) would allow you to easily handle the date. Anyway, if you want to procede in your way, check this: http://it2.php.net/strtotime and this: http://it2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php also, this: https://php.net/strftime Or simply use the explode function: http://it1.php.net/explode

Comment: OT: I hope that’s only a _bad_ example, because using those HTML elements would make little sense.

Answer (score 1):

Just use explode function.

for ex-

```
   <?php 
     $string='Tuesday, 8 April, 2014';
    $m=explode(' ',$string);
    ?>
    <p><?php echo $m[0] ?></p><p><?php echo $m[1] ?></p><p><?php echo $m[2] ?></p><p><?php echo $m[3] ?></p>
```

Comment: what about separating 8 april ?

Comment: ok. then use space in place of ','. i will edit this in my answer

Comment: good idea but i think this is not the proper way of doing this.

Comment: Perhaps, it depends on your needs it sure is the easiest, explode has always proven very helpful for php developers

Comment: @Mehar I believe `Sunny` has answered your question and should  be marked as accepted. Other than that, it's hard to say what you're looking for as far as results go. In my view, Sunny's answer does exactly what you asked for. You just need to be resourcesful and modify to suit; it's not "rocket science".

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string='Tuesday, 8 April, 2014';
$m=explode(' ',$string);
?>
<div><?php echo trim($m[0],','); ?></div>
<h1><?php echo $m[1]; ?></h1>
<h2><?php echo $m[2]; ?></h2>
<p><?php echo $m[3]; ?></p>
```